# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

Tags: javascript, vue.js

[image: web]

```
Vue.component('order-form', {
  props: ['orders'],
  data: function () {
    return {
      name: '',
      id: ''
    }
  },
  template:
    '<div>' +
    '<input type="name" placeholder="Write your name)" v-model="name"/>' +
    '<input type="button" value="Save" @click="save" />' +
    '</div>',

  methods: {
    save: function () {
      var order = { id: this.id, name: this.name };

      ordersApi.save(order).then(result =>
        result.json().then(data => {
          order.id = data,
            this.orders.push(order);
        })
      )
    }
  }
})
```

В массив `orders: []` методом `.push` не могу отправить order,
подскажите в чем проблема и как её решить?

---

я поменял строку this.orders.push(order); на this.orders = this.orders || []; this.orders.push(order);

выходит ошибка:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `this.orders = this.orders || []; this.orders.push(order);`

Comment: и что мне с этой строкой делать?

Comment: попробуйте убрать предложенный `this.orders = this.orders || [];` и инициализировать property со значением по умолчанию, как пишут в документации https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Validation

Comment: вставил код 
`props: {
        type: Object,
        default: 100
    }` 
выдает ошибку Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

Comment: `props: { orders: {type: Array, default: []} }`

Comment: выдает ошибку vue.js:634 [Vue warn]: Invalid default value for prop "orders": Props with type Object/Array must use a factory function to return the default value.

Comment: ну сделайте то, что вас просят (factory), в документации это есть

Comment: я не очень в этом разбираюсь